# C infinite loop issue when prompting

Tags: c, infinite-loop, scanf, rot13

Why in this code its doing an infinite loop without prompting again the user

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void to_rot13(char* value);

int main(){
    char word[1024];
    printf("C ROT13\nSome data to code or decode\n");
    while (1){
        printf(": ");
        scanf("%[^\n]s", word);
        to_rot13(&word);
        printf(": %s\n", word);
    }
    return 0;
}


void to_rot13(char* value){
    unsigned int x;
    for (x = 0; value[x] != '\0'; x++){
        if ((value[x] < 'A') || (value[x] > 'Z' && value[x] < 'a') || (value[x] > 'z')){}
        else if (tolower(value[x]) <= 'm'){value[x] = value[x] + 13;}
        else{value[x] = value[x] - 13;}
    }
}
```

I would like to prompt again the user
I can't be more precice.

Answer (score 3):

```
scanf("%[^\n]s", word);
```

leaves the newline in the input buffer, so the next `scanf` immediately returns without reading any further input, since the first `char` left in the buffer is a newline. You need to remove the newline from the input buffer.

```
int c;
do {
    c = getchar();
}while(c != '\n' && c != EOF);
if (c == EOF) {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); // input borked
}
```

Also, heed the compiler's warning and pass `word` instead of `&word` to `to_rot13`.

Comment: won't it just leave it in the buffer for the next read only (so you only get one repeat, not infinite repeats)?

Comment: No the next `scanf` again reads until it finds a newline, which it leaves in the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

You're sending &word to `to_rot13` (you should be sending word or &word[0])